# mod_rails and Paperclip problem Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, paperclip, mod-rails

I am havingn troble deploying my app to a server runing ubuntu with mod_rails. Runing webrick on the server seems fine and I can save files, no problem. But runing the app thru nginx, I get this error when I try to save a file.

[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #
R

Answer (score 4):

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path]
```

Is deprecated, apparently. Try:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```

Which worked for me. Adjust path to ImageMagick as needed.

Comment: worked for me too, MacOSX 10.6.3 with ImageMagick from MacPorts.

Comment: Nice!!  `/opt/local/bin` worked for me.  Mac OSX Snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

The path to ImageMagick is getting lost, try adding

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = '/opt/local/bin'
```

to your config.

Comment: that desn't seem to fix anything, I think it's got to do with the ngingx's ENV vars since runing a local webrick instancem works perfectly

Comment: Make sure you have the correct path.  I am running Ubuntu Server and it was actually "/usr/bin/" ... the trailing slash was key.

Answer (score 0):

If adding

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

doesn't work try installing `ImageMagick` with common delegates:

```
mkdir /sources cd /sources

wget
ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz

tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz

cd ImageMagick-6.6.7-8
```

Here comes the part makes the difference

```
./configure --disable-static
--with-modules --without-perl --without-magick-plus-plus --with-quantum-depth=8

make

sudo make install
```